# Sign in with apple using story board [SWIFT - Xcode11]

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, sign-in-with-apple

I want to integrate the Sign in with apple button using storyboard because its hard to programmatically do it because I have an existing User Interface for login form. with facebook google etc buttons, as I searched, i stumbled with this:

https://medium.com/takeaway-tech/sign-in-with-apple-storyboard-version-698c650956e7, it tells in the step

that "In your storyboard, add a view object, and set the control’s class value to ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton in Xcode’s Identity Inspector" can someone show a step in image on how to implement this? sorry i'm fairly new in coding swift iOS. much appreciated if someone can demonstrate how this control class value works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps to define a custom class for a generic view in Storyboard

[image]